# Differing ascii tables code values?

Tags: java, php, html, jsp, ascii

I'm trying to display an extended character on a mobile phone. The ascii value of 160 on my windows machine is á.

According to http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/ the ascii value of á is 225. Which one is correct ?

Can different hardware devices such as phones have a different ascii character set or do they all follow a standard ?

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: How did you check the value of á on your windows ?

Comment: There are no ASCII characters above 127. If you want to use characters above, you need to know the codepage. But better support Unicode if you can.

Comment: To check the value while pressing the alk key I type 160 which displays the á character.

Comment: What do you mean by the codepage ? I thought the extended ascii character set went to 255 ?

Comment: @user470184: There's no single codepage of "extended ASCII" - there are *lots* of codepages which are (unfortunately) known as extended ASCII, but which have extended ASCII in different directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page on wikipedia describes the different Alt Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_codes#Legacy_.28compatibility.29_methods)

If you type [alt]-0225 you get á (as it's using the ANSI code page that matches the current input locale -- [windows_1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252))

Without the leading 0, it's using DOS Compatability mode, and therefore a different Code Page

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, think I have a better undrstanding now.

Answer (score 5):

Ascii only defines codes 0..127. After that you're in the world of [code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page). You need to find out what code page is in use by Windows (it can vary) and your mobile phone (it may well vary there too)

Answer (score 1):

ASCII codes only go up to 127.  Anything beyond that is an extended code, and there is no single standard for those.

Answer (score 1):

There ascii chars from 32 to 127 are common to all different ascii tables. Chars from 128 to 255 are extended ascii and there are several variatons of them.

Answer (score 1):

Joel on Software has an excellent article about strings which you should read.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html